# Is there anyway to share eclipse key bindings across workspaces?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse key bindings follows workspaces. Is there anyway I can configure Eclipse so that it's global for the computer, not local for the workspace? Coming from Visual Studio, I find this solution one of the weirdest design decision of Eclipse.

I know about the import-export feature but I would like to not have to do that all the time.

Comment: Sorry Nilzor, wish I could answer. I do share your pain.

Comment: Why use multiple workspaces?

Comment: @davidcl To organize groups of projects and only work with one set of related projects at a time. I must admit I am not *that* experienced with Eclipse and this *might* be solved with Working Sets, but I read this blog once and got conviced: http://archive.darronschall.com/weblog/2006/01/getting-friendly-with-eclipse-workspaces.html

Comment: I've seen that before, but I think he's doing it wrong.  (I mean, you know, whatever works for him is fine, but he's not using the tool as it was intended to be used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that.  Switching workspaces is a slow, heavy, operation.

The "design decision" in Eclipse is that each developer has one workspace, which contains all of their projects.  The feature that's intended for switching between groups of related projects is Working Sets, perhaps in combination with Perspectives if the various working sets require different tool layouts.

The only good reason I can think of for using multiple workspaces would be if different projects required a totally different version or configuration of Eclipse.  Then, yes, you'd probably need a seperate workspace for each installation.  (But you wouldn't switch between them in the same copy of Eclipse!)

Most Eclipse settings are stored in the .metadata folder within the workspace root.  If I **had** to use multiple workspaces for some reason, I'd probably create an ant script or batch file (or shell script, depending on platform), that copies my .metadata file from my "main" workspace into the others, and hook it up to the build menu in Eclipse.  You could even create a custom launch for Eclipse that copies the .metadata into a workspace, then launches Eclipse pointed at that Workspace.

Comment: Only problem I have with Working Sets is that Eclipse seems to always compile all open projects in all working sets. So if I have a compile error in working set A while working with working set B, I can't run the project in B! I know I can close projects, but why should I have to? Is there any way to configure Eclipse to always close all projects in non-open working sets?

Comment: Hm, I'll have to look at this when I get to work, but I think the way I dealt with this issue was to use the "Build Working Set" command instead of "Build All"

Comment: Yeah, I just looked.  It's not as clean as I wish it was-- there's no "Build Current Working Set" command.  And in fact, I have CTRL-B bound to "build current project" which is the build command I use most often.

If you have groups of related projects where it is important to build those projects simultaneously, there is a handy "Close unrelated projects" command.  After doing that, "Build All" should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that and try to reorganize myself into Working Sets instead of Workspaces to solve my problem.